# How to put button for extension in firefox toolbar?

Tags: firefox

I have a few extensions installed; I can find out about them at the URL `about:addons`.

[image]

Two of them have buttons on the toolbar (along with some other buttons):

[image]

I want to put a button for the other one, `vgd2clipboard`, on the toolbar, also.  So I go to "Customize Firefox" from the preferences button (the three-slot toaster button on the extreme right of the toolbar):

[image]

I've clicked and dragged and undragged and wiggled and restarted and rebooted and shaken and stirred and googled, but I haven't found a way to get that button up there.  There doesn't seem to be any way to use that Extension `vgd2clipboard`.

**EDIT**: the other buttons were (apparently) installed as a side-effect of installing the Extensions.  I didn't do anything special to get the buttons for `1Password` and for `OneTab` in the toolbar.

Comment: This has to be added by the add-on author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vgd2clipboard uses the [sdk/widget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/widget) API to create its toolbar button, which was removed in Firefox 38 — that's probably why it no longer works. The extension itself is only a few lines of code, so fixing it would be trivial, but an even easier solution would be to find another URL-shortener extension.